# ASP MVC jQuery validation onfocusout working, but not on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I have a problem with my ASP MVC project and jQuery client side validation.
The problem is that when pressing the submit button, the form is validated but the errors are not displayed and the form gets submitted.
The problem is only appearing when i call valid() inside a validation method.
E.g.: i have a isdatebefore and isdateafter validation method.
I want to check if #start is before #end.
So when validating #start it also calles validate on #end to make sure error messages appear/disappear on both elements.
I added validation onfocusout and this is working just fine (on the #start and #ejnd fields and all other fields in the form).
However when I press the submit button, the form is validated (i placed some breakpoints to see if the method gets called), but is submitted although there are errors present.

Here is my code:

```
// Add IsDateAfter validation
$.validator.addMethod("isdateafter", function (value, element, params) {
    var self = $(element);
    var parts = element.name.split(".");
    var prefix = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; i++)
        prefix = parts[i] + ".";
    var otherElement = $('input[name="' + prefix + params.propertytested + '"]');
    var startdatevalue = otherElement.val();
    if (!value || !startdatevalue)
        return true;
    var allowequal = params.allowequaldates.toLowerCase() === "true";
    var start = Globalize.parseDate(startdatevalue);
    var end = Globalize.parseDate(value);
    if (!self.data('reval')) {
        self.data('reval', true);
        otherElement.data('reval', true);
        otherElement.valid();
        self.data('reval', false);
        otherElement.data('reval', false);
    }
    var isValid = allowequal ? start <= end :
        start < end;
    if (isValid) {
        self.removeClass('input-validation-error');
    }
    return isValid;
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
    'isdateafter', ['propertytested', 'allowequaldates'], function (options) {
        options.rules['isdateafter'] = options.params;
        options.messages['isdateafter'] = options.message;
    });

// Add IsDateBefore validation
$.validator.addMethod("isdatebefore", function (value, element, params) {
    var self = $(element);
    var parts = element.name.split(".");
    var prefix = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; i++)
        prefix = parts[i] + ".";
    var otherElement = $('input[name="' + prefix + params.propertytested + '"]');
    var startdatevalue = otherElement.val();
    if (!value || !startdatevalue)
        return true;
    var allowequal = params.allowequaldates.toLowerCase() === "true";
    var start = Globalize.parseDate(startdatevalue);
    var end = Globalize.parseDate(value);
    if (!self.data('reval')) {
        self.data('reval', true);
        otherElement.data('reval', true);
        otherElement.valid();
        self.data('reval', false);
        otherElement.data('reval', false);
    }
    var isValid = allowequal ? start >= end :
        start > end;
    if (isValid) {
        $(element).removeClass('input-validation-error');
    }
    return isValid;
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
    'isdatebefore', ['propertytested', 'allowequaldates'], function (options) {
        options.rules['isdatebefore'] = options.params;
        options.messages['isdatebefore'] = options.message;
    });
```

The code is working fine with the onfocusout event, but has problems wen called inside the onsubmit event.
When i remove the calls to otherElement.valid(); everything is working again (but i need to validate the other element for it to work correctly).

So does anybody know how i can keep validating both elements when validating one and still have it not screw up on submit?

Comment: How do you submit your form?

Comment: using a simple button: <button type="submit">Save</button>

Comment: Have you tried `<button type="submit" onclick="return validateForm()">Save</button>`? On the `validateForm()` function you can check for the form's validity

Comment: As I was saying, the jquery validation is called when the form is submitted, it just does not stop the form from being submitted and displays the errors instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `.valid()` method from within another jQuery Validate method.

[Use `.element()` instead](http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/validator/#validator-element())...

```
$('#yourForm').validate().element(otherElement);
```

or use keyword `this`, which represents the `validator` object from within the plugin's own methods...

```
this.element(otherElement);
```

or as you've already verified as working (*somewhat repetitive if the `this` keyword works*) ...

```
otherElement.parents('form').validate().element(otherElement);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! However you have to call otherElement.parents('form').validate().element(otherElement); as the element method is a member of the validator attached to the form. If you edit your answer, I will happily accept it :)

Comment: @wertzui, yes, you're correct, of course.  I just tested it and the `this` keyword also represents the `validator` object from within the method.

Comment: After having trouple with it again, I found out that using `this.element(otherElement);` calls `this.prepareElement( element );` which calls `this.reset();`. So this will break the validation on submit when a field that has been validated before (ie in the HTML markup it comes before) has been marked as invalid, because `this.reset();` will clear `this.errorList`. So instead of using `this.element(otherElement);` you must use `this.check(otherElement);`